# How to define element as "this"

Tags: jquery, this, element

The class `example` can have different heights because the middle one with "lorem ipsum" can spread over two rows because it has more text.

```
<div class="example">lorem</div>
<div class="example">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="example">lorem</div>
```

How can I identify this?
I want to know if a `.example` element has a bigger height than one row (e.g. 30px). So I want something like this:

```
if ($('.example').height() > 30) {
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
}
```

So every `.example` element that has a bigger height than `30px` shall have a green background color. How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: you need an event bind the class example which ever class made the event can have the $(this) context meaning it is the who trigger the event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height-function), inside callback `this` refers to the element

```
$('.example').height(function(i, v) {
   if(v > 30) {
       $(this).css('background', 'green');
   }
});
```

Comment: Why do i need the "i"?

Comment: @elterr1ble : in callback first argument is index and second is height value

Comment: @elterr1ble : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through all `example` divs.

```
$(".example").each(function()
{
    if ($(this).height() > 30)
        $(this).css("background", "green");
});
```